# pdfbookmark is not working if i used secnumdepth and \MakeUppercase

Tags: bookmarks

I would like to control `numbered, unnumbered section` through the  `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` command.

My requirement by default all the section heading should be unnumbered. So i will set default value `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. If i give the `\numbered` command all the head levels should be numbered. So i should create the command `\newcommand{\numbered}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}}`

Another requirement is `section` levels should be uppercase. So i am using the command `\MakeUppercase` command.

But the problem is raised below mentioned cases (BOOKMARK LINK NOT WORKING):

At the same time i am using two commands `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} and \MakeUppercase`, pdfbookmark is not working.

**Case 1.** `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` and `\MakeUppercase` both commands used - pdfbookmark is not working.

**Case 2.** `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` and `\MakeUppercase` both commands used - pdfbookmark is working.

I don't know first case is not worked. second case is worked. Please advice.

Alternatively i am using below mentioned pdfstring command. But this command is not working

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numbered}{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}}
\makeatother

\hypersetup{%
colorlinks,%
linkcolor=black,%
citecolor=gray,%
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=true,%
bookmarksnumbered=true,%
pdftitle={\@mytitle},%
pdfauthor={Maria Luisa Di Vona},%
pdfkeywords={},%
pdfsubject={}%
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-2.8ex}%
                                   {8.25pt}%
                                   {\raggedright\MakeUppercase}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{This is the sample title}
\author{Steven}

\maketitle


\section{This is the sample section one $\alpha$}

\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Second section}

\lipsum[5-10]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]

\section{This is the sample section two}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\MakeUppercase` also converts the name of the destination for the section to uppercase. The result is that the bookmark has the wrong link target.
The following example fixes it by moving `\MakeUppercase` to `\Sectionformat`, a macro introduced by package `nameref`, which is usually loaded in `\begin{document}`. The example loads the package earlier to redefine `\SectionFormat`. The first argument is the title, the second argument the level number.

Another issues:

- When package `bookmark` is loaded, the bookmarks are faster updated.
- `\alpha` is supported by Unicode bookmarks (option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto`) together with option `psdextra` to add lots of math symbols.
- The `\@mytitle` misses `\makeatletter`. Also it is undefined, therefore the example has directly put the title in `\pdftitle`. Also a macro can be defined, which is later used in option `pdftitle` and command `\title`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks,%
  linkcolor=black,%
  citecolor=gray,%
  bookmarksopen=true,%
  bookmarksnumbered=true,%
  pdfencoding=auto,%
  psdextra,%
  pdftitle={This is a sample title},%
  pdfauthor={Maria Luisa Di Vona},%
  pdfkeywords={},%
  pdfsubject={}%
}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax%
}

\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Sectionformat}[2]{%
  \ifnum#2=1 %
    \expandafter\MakeUppercase
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {#1}%
}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-2.8ex}%
                                   {8.25pt}%
                                   {\raggedright}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{This is the sample title}
\author{Steven}

\maketitle

\section{This is the sample section one $\alpha$}

\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Second section}

\lipsum[5-10]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]

\section{This is the sample section two}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\MakeUppercase` be made into `\@firstofone` rather than `\relax` in `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`?

Comment: @egreg Maybe a bit faster as `\@firstofone`, but the curly braces will be removed anyway.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Great Job. I am happy about your solution. I have an  doubt for this solution. What is the usage of \tracingmacros=1, \tracingmacros=1 and \expandafter commands?

Comment: @Vetti The `\tracingmacros` settings are just leftovers from testing. If `\tracingmacros` is larger than zero, then the macro expansions are written to the `.log` file.

Comment: @Vetri The `\expandafter` remove the `\else` branch and the `\fi` token, thus that `\MakeUppercase` and `\@firstofone` will see the intended argument as their argument `{#1}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I got the answer my question. Your answers is good.