# Defining Lead-In Heading [with capitals] breaks automatic hyperref's pdf bookmarks

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, hyperref

I am trying to define my own document class with some lead-in style heading text and pdf bookmarks.

Here is my class file `myclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\LoadClass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter

% disable section numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}    

% define lead-in section
\renewcommand\section{  
\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1ex}{-1.5ex}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}

\makeatother
```

And here is my document source `mydoc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext[5]


\section{Second Section}

\blindtext[5]


\section{Third Section}

\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

If I compile this with pdflatex I get the following warnings:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{section*.
3} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{section*.2} has been referenced but does not exist,
 replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{section*.1} has been referenced but does not exist,
 replaced by a fixed one
```

And pdf bookmarks do not go to their respective heading with clicked in the pdfviewer.

If the renewcommand below the comment `% define lead-in section` is removed. The bookmarks work fine (but then I won't have the heading style I was looking for. I'd strongly prefer to keep the automatic section labelling/bookmarking if possible. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271903/2388

Comment: I see so the bookmark was being modified the by style argument of the `section` command. The `pdfstringdefDisableCommands` in the linked question is not enough since that only acts on the `section` title argument instead of the output of `startsection`. The linked accepted answer fixes this by redefining `\Sectionformat` to upper case the section heading instead of using `startsection` for upper caseing the section heading.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the `\MakeUppercase`-variant of the [textcase](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase)-package and patch its underlying `\@uclcnotmath`-command to prevent case-changing also with `\Hy@SectionAnchorHref`, which, when hyperref is loaded, creates anchors/named destinations of sections:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@uclcnotmath}%
         {\@nonchangecase\ensuremath}%
         {\@nonchangecase\ensuremath\@nonchangecase\Hy@SectionAnchorHref}%
         {\message{!!! Patching successful !!!}}%
         {\message{!!! Patching failed !!!}}%
\makeatother


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%%%%
   \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-1ex}{-1.5ex}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext[5]


\section{Second Section}

\blindtext[5]


\section{Third Section}

\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

---

Things in use when writing/testing the code above:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.17)  30 JAN 2021 21:33
entering extended mode
[...]
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
[...]
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
[...]
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
[...]
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
[...]
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
[...]
Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
[...]
Package: babel 2020/12/16 3.52 The Babel package
[...]
File: babel.def 2020/12/16 3.52 Babel common definitions
[...]
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
[...]
```